# Python: Economic dispatch - Saving variables from a csv-data to a python variable

Tags: python, csv, variables

I am new to programming therefore I would be really grateful, if you have understandings for sort of "dumb" questions.

I try to solve an economic dispatch problem with lambda-iteration.

After plotting the functions for three generators, I tried to solve the main problem with the iteration method. Unfortunately, I can get the data from my csv-file to save as a variable (as you can see in my code).

Are there anything I didn't consider while saving my excel sheet to csv file (there is something written that it has to be in the form with commas or semicolons).
I always get the error message "name "a" is not defined".

I would really appreciate it, if someone could help me out!

```
Thanks in advance!

# Homework Project 2 (ED)

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import csv

# Plotting the cost functions for each generator

def gen1(x1):
    return  459 + 6.48*x1 + 0.00128*x1**2
x1 = np.arange(150,601,1)
y1 = gen1(x1)

def gen2(x2):
    return 310 + 7.85*x2 + 0.00194*x2**2
x2 = np.arange(100,401,1)
y2 = gen2(x2)

def gen3(x3):
    return 78 + 7.97*x3 + 0.00482*x3**2
x3 =np.arange(50,201,1)
y3 = gen3(x3)


plt.figure(figsize=(15,7))
plt.title('Generators')
plt.plot(x1, y1, label='Generator 1', color ='red')
plt.plot(x2, y2, label='Generator 2', color='blue')
plt.plot(x3, y3, label ='Generator 3', color='orange')
plt.xlabel('MW')
plt.ylabel('$/h')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

#Economic dispatch problem solving with by lambda-iteration technique

Load=823.65              # Power demand (MWh) at 13:00 Uhr 
data=pd.read_csv('/Users/ej/Desktop/project20220427/project2_new.csv')   # data about Gas turbines from the task sheet as csv-data[enter image description here][1]

a=data['a']              # a (€) values from fuel cost curves of Gas turbines 
b=data['b']             # b (€/MWh) values from fuel cost curves of Gas turbines  
c=data['c']            # c (€/MWh^2)values from fuel cost curves of Gas turbines 
Minimum_Capacity=data['Minimum_Cap']     #  Minimum capacitiy (MW) values of Gas turbines 
Maximum_Capacity=data['Maximum_Cap']     #  Maximum capacitiy (MW) values of Gas turbines 
Power_Demand=Load
Lambda=max(b)                  # assumed lambda value to solve the problem 

P = []
while abs(Power_Demand)>0.00001:   # Transmission losses are neglected 
    multiplier = (Lambda-b)/2
    P = np.divide(multiplier,c)
    P = np.minimum(P,Maximum_Capacity)
    P = np.maximum(P,Minimum_Capacity)
    Power_Demand=Load-np.sum(P)
    Lambda = Lambda+((Power_Demand*2)/(np.sum(np.add(1,c))))
    print(Power_Demand)

squaredP = np.multiply(P,P)

Fuel_Cost= np.add(a,np.multiply(b,P)+np.multiply(c,squaredP))         
# Fuel cost of the Gas turbines
print(Fuel_Cost) 
total_Fuel_Cost=np.sum(Fuel_Cost)     
# Total fuel cost of the plant to meet the demand 
print(total_Fuel_Cost)
#table(data(:,1),P,Fuel_Cost,'V',{'Unit' 'Power_Produced' 'Fuel_Cost'})
```

[CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzUMx.png)

Comment: Can you mention the error you are facing?

Comment: I always get the error message  - name "a" is not defined - .
I guess, it counts also for the other variables b, c, Minimum_Cap, Maximum_Cap.
Assume, that the columns couldn't be stored in the variables...

Comment: it basically means something is wrong in your 'a' column in your csv from /Users/ej/Desktop/project20220427/project2_new.csv. you should post your csv if you still can't figure out the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I uploaded also the csv-file. 
I will add it into the my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign header names.
If still getting the same issue, check your csv file if header name is present or not.

Make sure your csv file is comma seperated.

df = pd.read_csv('file', names=['Header1','Header2','Header3','Header4','Header5']

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
They are seperated by semicolons. Is this still acceptable or have they be seperated by commas?

Comment: Your code does not read in the csv file. I do not see how the error would occur. If you still have not solved your problem, do update your question.